# Does Kestrel server keep running when IIS / App pool craches

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Does Kestrel server keep running even after IIS or app pool crashes because I want to make sure that if there is any operation that is in progress does not get impacted when IIS or app pool crashes?

Comment: It should continue has if nothing appened. Kestrel is a completely separate server, 100% independent of IIS.

Comment: Rick described the process lifecycle, https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Mar/16/More-on-ASPNET-Core-Running-under-IIS#IISApplicationPoolLifetime

Comment: @Alejandro can you provide any supporting link.

Comment: @Lex Li the above blog does mention that kestrel server starts and stops when app pool starts and stops, but what about if app pool crashes?